# How to format a string object, whose content has {some_variable_name}?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a string object named `greeting`, and has content: `'Good {time}!'`

Suppose I then have an another string object named `time`, and has content: `'morning'`

I know if I now execute:

```
print(f'Good {time}!')
```

will print:

```
Good morning!
```

But how can I now make `greeting` has content: `'Good morning!'`

Comment: Hint: look up the documentation for f-strings, and in particular, look at the description of what they replaced/upgraded from.

Comment: I can't find the solution from the duplicate link, can anyone give a help?

Comment: See all the stuff in the duplicate link where it talks about the `.format` method? Do you understand, from the link, what that does? Do you see how you could use that to solve the problem?

Comment: I still can't find solution... Can you simply tell me, how to concrete the `greeting` variable in my question, Thank you!

Comment: I think maybe I can try to use eval()

Comment: No. You can use the `.format` method, as described in the linked duplicate. There are examples of usage there. This is not a code-writing service.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel
Please see my question again, I know how to use `.format()` normally